# How OMNeT lets vehicles and RSUs transmit data

Tags: veins

In tic toc, they are
 `tic. out - > {delay = exponential (200ms);} - > toc. in;`
The out gate is connected to the in gate and then transmitted through the out gate.
The following code:

```
CMessage * MSG = new cMessage ("tictocMsg");
Send (msg, "out");
```

But in the case of veins, how do they transmit data? I know it's wireless, but how exactly is it transmitted?

Answer (score 0):

As you correctly noted, Veins provides models for wireless communication. Both the vehicles, and the RSU use the `Nic80211p` model that provides wireless communication.

Connected models can pass messages to this model which will be received by neighboring nodes. For details on how this works internally, in particular the specific implementations of mac and phy layer that are used by the `Nic80211p` (`Mac1609_4` and `PhyLayer80211p`) are interesting, as well as the base classes of the phy, `BasePhyLayer` and `ChannelAccess`.

Comment: In a normal omnet project, I understand "Send (MSG, "out")", Sending MSG through "out" , but I can't understand how sending a message in Veins, thank you for your answer, but I should not consider the underlying MAC and PHY base class.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you want. If you simply want to know how to transmit data, have a look at the implementation of `TraCIDemo11p`. If you want to _understand_ how that works (as stated in your question), you will have to look at the mac and phy classes.

Comment: I'm asking the question because I don't know how the tracodemo11p class implements message transmission,I would be grateful if you would explain. sorry

Comment: `TraCIDemo11p` uses its `sendDown` method for message transmission, which is derived from its base class.

Comment: I checked the code and found that ***sendDown*** function is used for sending data, but I changed the map in the example provided by veins, and I don't know why RSU didn't receive the data sent by tracidemo11 class with ***sendDown***，Excuse me for disturbing you.

Comment: That can have various reasons, e.g., too large distance or a too crowded channel. Using the OMNeT++ GUI you can trace messages through the simulation and observe where they are lost.